Upgrading Microsoft.Identity.Web results in Ocelot error
I have a service that uses Ocelot to build a simple API gateway. I am attempting to upgrade Microsoft.Identity.Web from version 1.8.2 to 2.13.4.
When I make the library upgrade everything builds and starts but authorized endpoints fail with the error below. Is there a way to get more logging or details out of Ocelot?
I have looked at a successful JWT and a failing one and they are identical. My Ocelot version is 16.0.1 and the service is on dotnet 8.
The Error:
warn: Ocelot.Headers.Middleware.ClaimsToHeadersMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HN62RRG1II3K:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error setting headers on context, setting pipeline error
warn: Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HN62RRG1II3K:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: CannotFindClaimError Message: Cannot find claim for key: role errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/mypath/uid/local%7Cxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx, request method: GET

The relevant part of the Ocelot file looks like this:
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/v1/mypath/{everything}",
            "DownstreamScheme": "http",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "__MYPATH_API_HOST__",
                    "Port": 80
                }
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/mypath/{everything}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
                "OPTIONS",
                "GET",
                "PATCH",
                "POST",
                "PUT"
            ],
            "AuthenticationOptions": {
                "AuthenticationProviderKey": "MYKEY",
                "AllowedScopes": []
            },
            "AddHeadersToRequest": {
                "uid": "Claims[sub] > value > |",
                "role": "Claims[role] > value > |",
                "organizationGuid": "Claims[organization_guid] > value > |"
            }

